# Rake error while generating routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to generate routes (something that worked fine for a few weeks for the application I'm working on), and suddenly, I am seeing the following message:

```
You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

Doing bundle exec does not solve the problem. Looking through Gemfile.lock, I see the following:

```
railties (3.2.3)
  actionpack (= 3.2.3)
  activesupport (= 3.2.3)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
```

I tried changing that last line to:

```
rake (>= 0.9.2.2)
```

Which gives me the following error message:

```
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check if `rake` is there in your Gemfile. If it's not, add it, and specify the version "you already activated".

Then, you'll need to tell bundle to update the rake version it's using for your app:

`bundle update rake`

It'll update your `Gemfile.lock` for you.

Reason:

What happens is if you does not mention `rake` in your gemfile then new version of rails automatically install latest rake for you when you do `bundle install`. But your **gemfile** is locked with the older version. This causes problems and the error that you see comes.

So what you need to do is first you uninstall the latest rake version that was installed by using the command

```
gem uninstall rake
```

And then mention rake in your gemfile and do -

```
bundle update rake
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could try gem uninstall rake. You will be asked if you want to delete all versions - type - yes and then bundle install